# PhantomJS and Selenium: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using selenium 3.0.2 and PhantomJS to scrape some AJAX-values off one specific site. I am on Python 2.7, OS X 10.8.

I have had periods, where PhantomJS is working fine, and suddenly out of the blue it can't find the html I am looking for, although it is present and I **did not** change the code. 
Is PhantomJS prone to behaving erratically and is there another headless alternative that is more stable that works with my set-up? I can't get chromedriver to work.

**EDIT:** I am using

```
driver.get()    
time.sleep(5) #I have played with this value
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) #also played with this value up to 60...
try: 
   table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "bla bla")))
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't provide any details but i guess it is due to loading time of page, try to use Explicit Waits [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), It'll wait until your div loaded completely then you can perform other actions on the page.

Comment: I am actually using the Explicit Waits and it keeps timing out whatever timeout I set. The same site works fine with Firefox and I even have a `time.sleep()` after `driver.get()`. I have been struggling with this for weeks and as I'm a noob I'm kinda limited in understanding all the technical lingo when researching for possible issues. Thanks, tho!

Comment: Here is couple of things you can do to debug if same site/code works with firefox..
# Try to use latest version of phantomJs 
# when exception happen take a screen-shoot of page by using driver.save_screenshoot , and check the screen shoot for that layout area.

Comment: had a new built, did not work, now I downloaded ready-built, set driver to `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'], service_log_path='/tmp/ghostdriver.log')`, but nothing happens. No error, no output but the `print` Argument after setting `driver`never gets called.

Comment: I installed the already-built PhantomJS 2.1.1 and moved it into PATH. I set `driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)` and set `web driver.PhantomJS()`without all arguments. This works for now. Still not sure what the problem was after all. Thanks.